# How to (De)Serialize singleton property classes from XML

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, properties, singleton

I've got a little problem with deserializing information into singleton classes.

This is my current setup:

```
[XmlRoot("Root")]
public class SerializeTwoClasses
{
    ClassA _classA = ClassA.ClassAInstance;
    ClassB _classB = ClassB.ClassBInstance;

    public ClassA ClassAProp { get { return _classA; } set { _classA = value; } }
    public ClassB ClassBProp { get { return _classB; } set { _classB = value; } }
}

[XmlRoot("ClassARoot")]
public class ClassA
{

    static private ClassA _classA;

    static public ClassA ClassAInstance
    {
        get
        {
            if(_classA == null)
                _classA = new ClassA();

            return _classA;
        }
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot("ClassBRoot")]
public class ClassB
{

    static private ClassB _classB;

    static public ClassB ClassBInstance
    {
        get
        {
            if(_classB == null)
                _classB = new ClassB();

            return _classB;
        }
    }

    public int IdAndereClasse { get; set; }
    public string ValueAndereClasse { get; set; }
}
```

This is how I set the values and serialize.

```
SerializeTwoClasses _serializeTwoClasses = new SerializeTwoClasses();
_serializeTwoClasses.ClassBProp = new ClassB { IdAndereClasse = 753951, ValueAndereClasse = "Olla" };
_serializeTwoClasses.ClassAProp.Id = 789456;
_serializeTwoClasses.ClassAProp.Value = "The Title yo";
_serializeTwoClasses.ClassAProp.Address = new Address { City = "Amsterdam", HouseNo = 1, StreetName = "Some Street" };
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SerializeTwoClasses));
var fileStream =  new System.IO.StreamWriter("serialized.config");
serializer.Serialize(fileStream, _serializeTwoClasses);
fileStream.Close();
```

the output in the file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <ClassAProp>
    <Id>789456</Id>
    <Value>The Title yo</Value>
    <Address>
      <HouseNo>1</HouseNo>
      <StreetName>Some Street</StreetName>
      <City>Amsterdam</City>
    </Address>
  </ClassAProp>
  <ClassBProp>
    <IdAndereClasse>753951</IdAndereClasse>
    <ValueAndereClasse>Olla</ValueAndereClasse>
  </ClassBProp>
</Root>
```

Now I want to deserialize the info from the file into the classes and gave it a try like this:

```
SerializeTwoClasses _serializeTwoClasses = new SerializeTwoClasses();
XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SerializeTwoClasses));
TextReader reader = new StreamReader("serialized.config");
object obj = deserializer.Deserialize(reader);
_serializeTwoClasses = (SerializeTwoClasses)obj;
reader.Close();
```

when I examine the _serializeTwoClasses object, I can see the _ClassA and _ClassB properties and they represent the values which were set in the serialized.config file.
but...although the classes ClassA and ClassB are only referenced to created via a singleton method< I would have expected both classes to be filled with the values from the file. But they are not...

In my form class (I trigger the above serialize and deserialize methods via a button) I have these fields in the class:

```
ClassA _classA = ClassA.ClassAInstance;
ClassB _classB = ClassB.ClassBInstance;
```

(set before serializing and deserializing)
And the content of both classes represent the default value of the properties (0,null, etc...).
What am I overlooking???

By the way: the property classes need to be a singleton class, due to the setup in the framework.
Kind regards,

Matthijs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your types are not true singletons; they are types with a default instance. The deserialize step has created a second **entirely separate** instance. You can check, for example:

```
bool areSame = ReferenceEquals(
    _serializeTwoClasses.ClassAProp, ClassA.ClassAInstance);
```

which I would expect to be `false`.

Comment: the bool is indeed false. Do you have any thought on how to get it working correctly?

Comment: @user369122 define "correctly". In my opinion it *already is* working correctly...

Comment: yeah, you got a point here ;-) But I think you understand my intentions with the code. I would like to be able to deserialize the values from the file and add them to classes ClassA and ClassB in a way that I can use the values of ClassA and ClassB in different classes / methods. And when I update one of the properties, the value can also be used in another instance of the class. I thought I took care of that by using the singleton implementation, but apparently not :-)

Comment: @user369122 see, I can suggest ways to "fix" it, but IMO they just **break it in other ways**. For example, you could make the *instance* properties talk to *static* fields - that is just evil in about a dozen ways, but would work. Frankly, I'm of the view that serialization should work against DTOs, and should be simple - and then *after* (de)serialization you can do *whatever code you need to* to get the system how you want it - for example, copying values from the deserialized DTO instance into the singleton instance.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions, I'll go and play around with the code some more to find an "elegant" solution.